# How to recenter vertically in GVR / Cardboard unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Calling

```
GvrViewer.Instance.Recenter ();`
```

only recenters the view horizontally, i need it also vertically.

I'm using the latest unity beta and GVR 0.8`

Comment: What is `GvrViewer` then?

Comment: @Droppy A class from Google Vr API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recenter by making your VR camera object a child of another object (let's call it parent) and rotating the parent in the opposite direction of the rotation of your VR camera. This simple script will do (attach to parent):

```
public class Recenterer:MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Transform VRcam;  // drag the child VR cam here in the inspector

    public void Recenter()
    {
      transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(VRcam.rotation);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Google VR SDK 1.50 (and Unity 5.6) you can do

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(newRot.x, newRot.y, newRot.z);
UnityEngine.VR.InputTracking.Recenter();
```

also, if you don't want to get confused you also need to catch the GvrEditorEmulator instance and Recenter it as well.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        gvrEditorEmulator.Recenter();
#endif
```

Recentering GvrEditorEmulator though doesn't seem to work very well at the moment but if you disable it you'll see the recentering works for the main camera.